# Change background of Item in dropdownlist in Kendo UI Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I have requirement to highlight the text and change background color based on some condition in the dropdownlist.
I did some search on official kendo forum but i didn't find anything related to the dropdownlist.
Can anyone please guide me or suggest a way out on how to fix the issue.
[image]

Comment: I believe this might be what you are looking for https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/templates/

Comment: As I have nothing selected. I would like to highlight only 1977 in this case, or current year.

Comment: You could try to set the selected element equal the currently latest date, if you mean to select the date by default. Otherwise do similar, but with `[ngClass]` binding a highlight class to the template where the value is equal to the latest date.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It would have been great if you could have shared an small snippet, as things are bit different with the telerik controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to get a clue, finding how to highlight a Option in the dropdownlist, this feature is now available in the latest version of the Telerik Dropdownlist(5.4.0).

In the telerik control, the items are displayed using  rather than using the . It was bit challenging to handle that.

In order to highlight an item from the list, the DropDownList provides a **focusItemAt** method that allows the developer to focus an item at a given index.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <kendo-dropdownlist
        #dropdownlist
        [data]="listItems"
        textField="text"
        valueField="value"
        [valuePrimitive]="true"
        (open)="highlight($event, dropdownlist)"
      >
      </kendo-dropdownlist>
    `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  public listItems: Array<{ text: string; value: number }> = [
    { text: 'A', value: 1 },
    { text: 'B', value: 2 },
    { text: 'C', value: 3 },
  ];

  highlight(e, dropdownlist) {
    dropdownlist.focusItemAt(3);
  }
```

Hope, this helps.